# C# Set property desde la clase

Tags: c#, xamarin, props, set

tengo esta clase y quiero  hacer set de una property con el valor de otras dos propiedades que tengo para poder hacer binding despues, en este caso **AccessibilityTitlePaymentType** es la propiedad que quiero hacer set.
Esto es lo que estoy intentando hacer, pero cuando hago el binding el valor me aparece vacio.

```
public class MyClass
{
 [JsonProperty("PaymentType")]
        public string PaymentType { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("PaymentDate")]
        public string PaymentDate { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("MethodPayment")]
        public string MethodPayment { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("LastFour")]
        public string LastFour { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("ConfirmationCode")]
        public string ConfirmationCode { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("DueAmount")]
        public string DueAmount { get; set; }

        private string _accessibilityTitlePaymentType;
        public string AccessibilityTitlePaymentType
        {
            get => _accessibilityTitlePaymentType;
            set
            {
                _accessibilityTitlePaymentType = PaymentType + " " + DueAmount;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Si quieres una propiedad que su valor sea una suma de otros valores simplemente colocalo en el GET, y el SET no lo agregas, será un propiedad READONLY (porque no tendrá set, ya que no lo necesitarás) no te compliques seteando valores que ya existen, solo retórnalos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es un poco rara esa propiedad que estás creando. No tiene mucho sentido que un `set` no haga nada con el valor recibido (`value`). Para que eso te funcionara, deberías asignar cualquier valor a `AccessibilityTitlePaymentType` para que almacenara el valor en la propiedad. Si no haces ninguna asignación, el valor de la propiedad estará vacio.

Lo que quieres entiendo que es tener una propiedad que te devuelva una unión de otras dos. Para eso lo que debes hacer es que tu propiedad solo tenga la parte del `get`, y devolver ahi el valor:

```
public string AccessibilityTitlePaymentType
{
    get => PaymentType + " " + DueAmount;
}
```